# Can mod_deflate compress the output depending on the "Host" header in the Request Headers?

Tags: apache, apache2, zlib, mod-deflate

Can mod_deflate compress the output depending on the "Host" header in the Request Headers?
As far as I understand based on the documentation, it is usually done by looking at the User-Agent etc. in the configuration.

I could not find any example in doc that says -

```
If Host: header is x.y.z then do compression. Else don't do compression.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the manual:

> Compression is implemented by the DEFLATE filter. The following directive will enable compression for documents *in the container where it is placed:*

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
```

Didn't test it, but "container" should include "<VirtualHost>", so just place it only in those VHs you want to deliver compressed responses.

Comment: Yes, `SetOutputFilter` is valid in a vhost context according to the Apache docs. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#setoutputfilter